# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Fault occurred while processing

Tags: php, soap, xml-parsing, wsdl, soap-client

I use this code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$params = array(
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'cocNo' => '1060907A'
);

$client = new SoapClient('URL/?wsdl',array('trace'=>1));
//$response = $client->__getTypes();
$response = $client->__getFunctions();
pint_r($response);
```

and get this successful response:

```
Array ( [0] => verifyResponse verify(verify $parameters) )
```

but when i use this code

```
$response = $client->__soapcall('verify',array($params));
```

I got this response error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Fault occurred while processing. in /PATH/index.php:22 
Stack trace: #0 /PATH/index.php(22): SoapClient->__soapCall('verify', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /PATH/index.php on line 22
```

What is wrong with my call?

Answer (score 1):

According to `$client->__getTypes()` you are missing an 'arg0' element in your data structure.  Change your code to:

```
try 
{
  $response = $client->verify(array('arg0' => $params));
} 
catch(Exception $e)
{
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```